# Combining multiple values attached to the same variable in Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I need to add multiple values related to the same variable into one single entry. Here is what my worksheet looks like:

```
    ColA   ColB   ColC
    Onion  Ounces  12
    Onion  Ounces  6
    Carrot Kilo    3
    Basil  Grams   25
    Carrot Kilo    6
    Basil  Cups    3
```

Here is what I am trying to figure out how to do:

```
    ColA   ColB   ColC
    Onion  Ounces  12
    Onion  Ounces  6
    Carrot Kilo    3
    Basil  Grams   25
    Carrot Kilo    6
    Basil  Cups    3
    __________________
    Onion  Ounces  18
    Carrot Kilo    9
    Basil  Grams   25
    Basil  Cups    3
```

*If colA matches (both entries are 'Basil'), but colB doesn't match (one entry is 'ounces' and one is 'cups') it needs to have separate entries.

I'm very new to excel and not even sure how to phrase this question correctly, so my apologies if this has been answered many times before!

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: have a look at that SUMIFS function (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en):

```
=QUERY(A1:C6,"Select A,B,Sum(C) group by A,B")
```

[image]

Comment: I never knew that you can write a query in google sheets. But there is no way he/she is going to understand how this works. Which is a problem because again SO will have to answer any other simple questions that he/she may have